# Cisco Router - not saving nat routing information in startup script

Tags: networking, nat, configure, cisco-router

I have a client with an old Cisco Router (*Cisco 2851 (revision 53.51)*), using *Cisco IOS Software, 2800 Software (C2800NM-IPBASE-M), Version 12.4(3i)*.

I needed to open a new routing port to a computer in the sub-net. After looking I managed to do it successfully with:

```
conf term
ip nat inside source static udp  <internalIP4> 1234 <externalip> 1234
end
```

It all works fine with the routing, I managed to access the computer and see the result in: `show ip nat translations`.
**Problem started today after a shortage of electricity which the router seems to have "erased" that line from configurations**

Taking a look at the startup script (with `show startup`) I managed to see in the routing session something like this:

```
!         
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http timeout-policy idle 60 life 86400 requests 10000
ip nat pool intLan <externalIP> <externalIP> netmask 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside source list 1 pool intLan overload
ip nat inside source static tcp <internalIP1> 41 <externalIP> 41 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp <internalIP2> 14 <externalIP> 14 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp <internalIP2> 14 <externalIP> 14 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp <internalIP2> 114 <externalIP> 114 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp <internalIP2> 114 <externalIP> 114 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp <internalIP3> 345 <externalIP> 345 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp <internalIP3> 345 <externalIP> 345 extendable
!
```

So old routes, however my new route doesn't show.

Could you please help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: try using two times `end` after the setup

Comment: Did you `wr mem`, as in `write memory`? If you did not, and the router rebooted, then of course it will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Albin, unf that didn't help.

Comment: @Bib Thank you so much! It worked. Didn't know about that, knew it had to be something as simple as this.

Comment: It's actually a good way of backing out a change if it goes wrong... Make a change, if your session does not respond, then just reboot it before doing `wr mem`. You should also look at the `reload` command if you make a config mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Cisco devices, when making changes, it only makes changes to the `running config`, not `startup config`, which is held in flash.

To store it in flash, use `write memory`, and this can be verified by `show start` which will have the date embedded within the file. To see what is actually running, use `show run`.

This allows any changes which have been made and has *broken* the config to be backed out by performing a reboot. This is done with the `reload in ...` command. In that you run the reload command then make the change. If it has failed, the device will eventually reboot. If it has worked, then you should run `reload cancel` to stop the reboot.